# Using django prefetch_related() to get the time of last activity

Tags: django

I upgraded to Django 1.7 so I could get `Prefetch objects`, but I'm having a hard time getting them to behave as expected.

I have an Employee model like this:

```
class Employee(Human):
  ... additional Employee Fields ...

  def get_last_activity_date(self):
    try:
        return self.activity_set.all().order_by('-when')[0:1].get().when
    except Activity.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

and activities like this

```
class Activity(models.Model):
  when = models.DateTimeField()
  employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='activity_set')
```

I want to use prefetch_related to get the last activity date for this employee.  I've tried to express this many ways, but no matter how I do it, it ends up generating another query.  My other 2 my prefetch_related parts work as expected, but this one does not ever seem to save me any queries.

I'm using this with Django Rest Framework, so I really need the prefetch_related part to work since I have no way of reaching inside DRF to do the mapping outside of the queryset.

Here is one of the ways that **DOES NOT WORK**

```
def get_queryset(self):

    return super(EmployeeViewSet, self).get_queryset()\
           .prefetch_related('phone_number_set', 'email_address_set')\
           .prefetch_related(Prefetch('activity_set', Activity.objects.all().order_by('-when')))\
           .order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
```

Notice that on the activity_set prefetch query that I can't slice to only get the latest entry either which is a concern in terms of how much memory this is going to eat up.

I do actually see the prefetch query take place, but then each employee gets a separate query for that piece of information, meaning I have one bigger wasted query and still get the ~200 querys I'm trying to prevent.

How do you get the prefetch_related to work for me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect You are missing the point of `prefetch_related`. The docs [state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) that this is the expected behavior: many queries and the 'joining' in python. If you want less queries you should use `select_related` Also I'm not sure It would work with your specific models (not stated in the question) since select_related does work well with many to many relations.

**UPDATE - the docs:**

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, **does a separate lookup** for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python

Comment: `selected_related` won't work for this relationship.  `select_related` only works if the ForeignKey is on the Employee.  Not on a reverse relationship.  When `prefetch_related` is working, you get one query for all the employees which then pull their data from that single query.

Comment: I suspected you models won't support select_related here. But you are wrong about the meaning of prefetch_related. It would do many queries, It's explicit in the docs..

Comment: Read a little closer, it does one query per relationship, not per model per relationship.  Like I said above, 2 other prefetch_related are working just fine.  This one is different in that it is try to get the most recent of many.  I'm also using DjDT to look at the queries and they are what I would expect, all of them, except the extra query per model instance around last activity.