# Django query to get the latest activity entry for each employee

Tags: django

I have a list of employees and I want to know the last activity they completed.

```
class Employee(Human):
    ... additional Employee Fields ...

    def get_last_activity(self):
        try:
            return self.activity_set.all().order_by('-when')[0:1].get()
        except Activity.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

`get_last_activity` above will do what I want for a single instance.  But if I call this method once for each employee in the list, I rack up several hundred additional queries.

Activity looks like this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    when = models.DateTimeField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='activity_set')
    ...additional activity fields...
```

The query looks like this:

```
Employee.objects.all.annotate(last_activity_timestamp=Max('activity_set__when'))\
    .filter(Q(activity_set__when__lte=timezone.now()) 
            | Q(activity_set__when__isnull=True))\
    .order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
```

The list of activities includes future planned activities, so I have to filter with `activity_set__when__lte=timezone.now()`

This gets me an employee record with an extra member named last_activity_timestamp when the query is run.  I want to get the entire activity record for the last_activity, rather than just the one part from the annotation.

In english: give me each employee in a list, and include with each employee, all the details of the last activity they did in a field named last_activity.  Do this in a single query.

This has proven VERY hard to accomplish, so I must be missing something fundamental.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355500/using-django-prefetch-related-to-get-the-time-of-last-activity) which is another approach I was taking to get to the same end result.  Neither of them are doing what I want.

Comment: Have you tried to select max(when) on the Activity model, grouping by employee_id? And then using a .selected_related('employee')?

Comment: return self.activity_set.all().order_by('-when').reverse[0] ?

Comment: @elmonkeylp  That's what the code above is doing, and that results in one query per employee instance.

Comment: @Tiago trying to figure out how I could feed this into a Django Restframework serializer for the Employee.....

Comment: @Mark0978: try to see if it works on the django console. If it works, you can figure out how to do it using your framework or trying asking a specific question about using different models on Django Restframework.